# SVG Clip Path not working

Tags: css, html, svg

I am a novice web developer, so go easy on me. I am trying to make a custom shaped element in the shape of the united states. In my html, I created an svg element with a clipPath child, and a polygon element child of that showing the coordinate points it must go through, but it doesn't show. Below is my HTML and CSS.

---

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
</head>
<body>

<svg width="100" height="100">
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="129 43,114 250,389 272,390 54,125 42">
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### CSS

```
/*Chrome,Safari*/
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(129px 43px,114px 250px,389px 272px,390px 54px,125px 42px);

/*Firefox*/
clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");
```

Comment: Also this was just a test with a trapezoidal shape, not actually a united states shape.

Comment: So... you've defined a clip path in two places - your SVG and your CSS. But you're not drawing anything anywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath,

> The clipping path restricts the region to which paint can be applied.

So you won't actually see the effect of this until you actually try to draw something, like so

```
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
    <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
        <polygon points="129 43,114 250,389 272,390 54,125 42">
        </polygon>
    </clipPath>
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="1000" width="1000" fill="red" clip-path="url('#clipPolygon')"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with not working clip path in few versions of FireFox. I found that having css `mix-blend-mode` property as `multiply` was causing the issue.

My fix was to remove that CSS property when particularly on those versions of FireFox. It was a mix of JS and CSS code.

If you are using Modernizr - it is probably another easy way to determine the browser version and use css based on that.